# How to open different class on each row of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So i need to start an activity when i click on different rows of recyclerview. I just cant figure out how I tried this code 
but seems to be not working

```
class MyViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private final Context context;

public MyViewholder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    context = itemView.getContext();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    final Intent intent;
   switch (getAdapterPosition()){
        case 0:
            intent =  new Intent(context, CalendarControllerFrancisco.class);
            break;

        case 1:
            intent =  new Intent(context, CalendarControllerB.class);
            break;

        case 2:
            intent =  new Intent(context, CalendarControllerNa.class);
            break;

        default:
            intent =  new Intent(context, CalendarController.class);
            break;
    }
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

public class LocationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private ArrayList<LocationModel> dataSet;
Boolean check = false;
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
//private final Context context;
    TextView locat;


    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
       // context = itemView.getContext();
        this.locat = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.wordtext);
    }
}


public LocationAdapter(ArrayList<LocationModel> data) {
    this.dataSet = data;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_view_row,parent,false);
   MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
   return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    TextView word1 = holder.locat;
    word1.setText(dataSet.get(position).getLocations());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
}
```

Comment: what is your logic for different?

Answer (score 0):

You need add **setOnClickListener event** for one component.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    TextView word1 = holder.locat;
    word1.setText(dataSet.get(position).getLocations());
    word.setOnClickListener(holder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> RecyclerItemClickListener

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
}
}
```

> Define ClickListener as same as ListView onItemClickListener

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(  
    new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
     // TODO Handle item click
  }
})
);
```

Comment: what do you mean by this? should I create this class RecyclerItemClickListener? , if not where would i place it. sorry Im new to this

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    final Intent intent;
   switch (getAdapterPosition()){
        case 0:
            intent =  new Intent(context, CalendarControllerFrancisco.class);
            break;

        case 1:
            intent =  new Intent(context, CalendarControllerB.class);
            break;

        case 2:
            intent =  new Intent(context, CalendarControllerNa.class);
            break;

        default:
            intent =  new Intent(context, CalendarController.class);
            break;
    }}
```

The ViewHolder is a container used by the adapter to fill in item data arbitrarily depending on the RecyclerView items to be displayed. Hence it shouldn't have access to any position data from the item list to identify itself. You are confusing concepts.

Try replacing the above with something like:

```
class MyViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

private final Context context;
int type;

public MyViewholder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    context = itemView.getContext();
}

public void bind(int type) {
    this.type = type;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    final Intent intent;
    switch (this.type){
        case 0:
            intent =  new Intent(context, CalendarControllerFrancisco.class);
            break;

        case 1:
            intent =  new Intent(context, CalendarControllerB.class);
            break;

        case 2:
            intent =  new Intent(context, CalendarControllerNa.class);
            break;

        default:
            intent =  new Intent(context, CalendarController.class);
            break;
    }
}

}
```

Then, in your Adapter use onBindViewHolder callback to access the item collection and assign their type for the creation of every item. 
Something like:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.bind(myItemList.get(position).type());

}
```

Comment: @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.bind(myItemList.get(position).type());

}